# How do I add a vertical divider in android studio using ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want to add a `ViewAnimator` using `ConstraintLayout`. I did it using `RelativeLayout` but I am not able to do the same using `ConstraintLayout`. In fact there isn't any such option, there is horizontal and vertical divider. The screenshot given is what I want using `ConstraintLayout`, I did that with `RelativeLayout`. Here is the code for `ViewAnimator`

```
<ViewAnimator
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
```

I only need the vertical line

[image: Just like this screenshot done using RelativeLayout]

Comment: where are you stuck please share your snippet of code.

Answer (score 4):

Set the height `0dp` and then use topof and bottomof parent or any view.

```
    <ViewAnimator
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
```

also for vertical div you can use `<View />` tag.